# Is it just me or when driving down the pits, the pit wall will always be on the left?

Tags: formula-1

I think at every track, when you are driving down the pit lane, the pit wall will always be on the left, and the stands on the right.

Am I right on this? If I am, is there a logical reason why it always ends up this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the exception of Monaco, which is an oddball in many regards, the pit wall is always on the side of the pit lane closest to the track, so that the team personnel can hold up the drivers' pit boards. Whether this is the left or right side of the pit lane differs from circuit to circuit, depending on which side of the pit straight the pit lane is on.

However, I can understand where your belief comes from. Of the 21 circuits used in the 2019 season, 15 had their pit wall on the left-hand side. ImClarky correctly named the six that didn't, in a now-deleted comment: Monaco, Singapore, Circuit of the Americas, Baku, Montreal, and Interlagos.

Of those 15 circuits, all but Yas Marina were clockwise, and so had their pit lane on the inside of the circuit. Why pit lanes are so frequently on the inside, I can't say, but it may make for an interesting research topic if I have time later.

So not *all* F1 circuits have their pit wall on the left, but *most* do, presumably as a side-effect of [F1 circuits tending to be clockwise](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/why-are-formula-1-tracks-usually-oriented-clockwise?rq=1).

Comment: "Why pit lanes are so frequently on the inside, I can't say" I'd assume it was because you have land inside the racetrack that would otherwise be wasted. May as well put the pit facilities in there.

Comment: @PeterGreen Most importantly, I would argue, it is much easier to put what is often one of the major grandstands on the outside of the circuit along the start/finish straight overlooking the pitlane and the rest of the circuit. Putting it on the inside would mean spectators would have to cross over/underneath the race track (which is possible for quite a few circuits, like Silverstone, but somewhat inconvenient), and importantly would not see any of the rest of the circuit in all but very few cases (Sepang comes to mind where you would still see a large part of the circuit from the inside).

Comment: In Canada the wall is on the right because the pits are on the outside of the circuit.

Comment: Montreal is a special case: they can't put the pit lane on the inside because the inside is occupied by a big lake. Donington Park is the only other clockwise circuit I can think of that has its pit lane on the outside, but I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 2):

No, and it doesn't seem to be perfectly correlated with track direction either.

Montreal and Austin both have the pit lane to the right of the pits, and they race in opposite directions.